# Client not receiving json response from server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, jwt

i am building a small social media app, the problem i have is that when my component mounts, i send a get request to my backend, but the client doesn't get the specified json response, it instead throws a 400 error but when i check the network tab i get the correct response. Mind you, i am using a setupProxy.js file to proxify my request.

See frontend code for fetching data

```
      const fetchUser = async () =>{
        try{
          console.log('Dev')
          let res = await axios({
            method: 'get',
            url: `${USER_SERVER}/auth`,
          })
        }catch(err){
          console.log(err.message)
        }
      }
      fetchUser()
    })
```

see backend code

```
 const User = require("../models/user");
require("dotenv").config();
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

let auth = async (req, res, next) => {
  let token = req.cookies.w_auth;
  try {
    let decoded = await jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRETKEY);
    const user = await User.findOne({ _id: decoded, token: token })
      .select("-token");
    if (!user) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        isAuth: false,
        error: true
      });
    }
    req.token = token;
    req.user = user;
    next();
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(400).send({
      isAuth: false,
      error: true,
      verification: false,
    });
  }
};

module.exports = { auth };
```

see setupProxy.js file for proxifying request

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require("http-proxy-middleware");
//const express = require('express')


module.exports = function (app) {
  app.use(
    '/api',
    createProxyMiddleware({
      target: "http://localhost:8080/",
      changeOrigin: true,
    })
  );
};
```

see error message in console.

```
xhr.js:177 GET http://localhost:3000/api/users/auth 400 (Bad Request)
```

see network tab result

**{isAuth: false, error: true, verification: false}**

Comment: You can put console.log to server part to see what error it throws.

Comment: the server is working fine, i have tested it on the console an also with postman

Comment: Server returns error ```  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(400).send({
      isAuth: false,
      error: true,
      verification: false,
    });```

Answer (score 0):

Can return error from backend, at least will see what happening

```
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(400).send({
      isAuth: false,
      error,
      verification: false,
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think i have been able to solve it, the problem was coming from my auth middleware.

I had to remove the await keyword from the verify function and i also returned my response without a status code.
Below is the correct code.

```
const User = require("../models/user");
require("dotenv").config();
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

let auth = (req, res, next) => {
  let token = req.cookies.w_auth;
  try {
    let decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRETKEY);
    /**Recall that the payload used, was the user id **/
    User.findOne({ _id: decoded, token: token })
    .select('-token')
    .then((user) => {
      if (!user) {
        return res.json({
          isAuth: false,
          error: true,
        });
      }
      req.token = token;
      req.user= user;
      next();
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message)
    return res.json({
      isAuth: false,
      error: true,
      verification: false
    })
  }
};


module.exports = { auth };
```